# Adding a .on event on each option in a combo box in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a way to add an id to each option created dynamically or where do I use the onClick event within a dynamically created option.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you'll be better off binding to the select's `onchange` event. From there you can check its current value to know which option was just selected.

Comment: Right, but how do I tie a value to each option?

Comment: Post some code on how you are generating the OPTION tags for the SELECT control. The value for the options are defined like this <option value="some value">This is my option label</option>. Then bind to the onchange of the SELECT control instead and you can get its val() which will be the selected value in the drop-down.

Comment: In Dojo, I believe you can do dijit.byId('yourSelect').displayedValue

Answer (score 0):

`OPTION` tags do not have click events. You need to hook into the `onchange` of the parent `SELECT` tag.